# using Open Font License (OFL) in commercial project

Tags: license-compatibility, ofl

I was searching for better fonts and icons and ended up on Google Fonts. I was able to download the fonts for free which were under OFL. According to the included license file,

> The fonts and derivatives, however, cannot be released under any other
>   type of license. The requirement for fonts to remain under this
>   license does not apply to any document created using the fonts or
>   their derivatives.

My Questions,

1. If I'm using this for a commercial web application project, I *need not to* mention the font source and/or the license as well?
2. Is it advised to use OFL fonts in commercial projects *with custom licenses* which are not open-source?

Comment: Does this OFL FAQ answer your question? http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#1b11b702

Comment: It looks to me that you have already answered your question. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

> My Questions,
>
> 1/ If I'm using this for a commercial web application project, I need not
> to mention the font source and/or the license as well?
>
> 2/ Is it advised to use OFL fonts in commercial projects with custom
> licenses which are not open-source?

You may not **need** to mention the font source &/or licence but it is generally considered polite to do so as one or more people may well have spent 100s of hours on the work.

In general it is usually considered fine to use OFL fonts **unmodified** in non-open source products but it is polite, *(and advisable)*, to mention that you have used them *possibly as a footnote to your license* that they are present.

What you **cannot** do is modify the font and then redistribute it under a different license.

*The usual disclaimers that I am not a legal expert in any country let alone the readers apply!*